# Swing thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Suppose I have a multithreaded program which takes multiple files, and each thread reads lines from one of the files and updates the GUI window by appending each line to a TextArea in the GUI. The method to append to the TextArea is registered as a callback method to the thread. How can I make sure that the append operation is thread safe? I have read that I should use `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater`; is the invokeLater method itself threadsafe? That is, inside the callback function do i just need to create a Runnable for updating the TextArea and call invokeLater on it? (the callback method is not synchronized)

Comment: Yes, invokeLater() is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading each line, you need to call a block like:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    myTextArea.append(myLine);
    myTextArea.repaint();
  }
});
```

This could have considerable performance issues, since you are essentially synching all of your text line updates on the GUI thread. It might be smarter to use a thread-safe (ie synchronized) queue for the read lines, and a java.swing.Timer that reads from that queue and does updates periodically

Comment: You don't need `myTextArea.repaint()`

Comment: You push multiple `Runnable`s into the EDT queue via `invokeLater` so that's not much of a difference to queing them manually. Unless you do batching of updates.

Comment: It would not be safe to directly call `append` from the call back method, correct?

Comment: @SimonZhu no, it would not be safe to call append from the call back method

Comment: @ControlAltDel please whats reason for `myTextArea.repaint();`